# Type reinterpreting and memory pooling in C#

Tags: c#, memory-management, pool

Is it possible to create a buffer of bytes and then use it to allocate different types of data. Also can it be done in a managed way (maybe with span/memory)?

I come from a C++ background where I would create buffers of bytes on the heap and then reuse them to allocate most of my data types. So if what I'm asking is not possible in a safe way, can I allocate memory on the native heap and then reinterpret my data as different types? Are there any type punning or type aliasing rules I should be aware of in C#?

Comment: Yeah, we don't do that here :D ... But seriously: what are you trying to do? _Usually_ you shouldn't worry about memory allocation (until you _need to_ optimize).

Comment: Maybe but managed means managed. The system is made to do it for you and not that you do it yourself.  This question is in the "working against the system" area and you may come up with a good reason first better then "it the way i'm used to from c++".

Comment: .... or as Master Lee would say: "Empty your cup."

Comment: That was possible [years ago](https://www.wiktorzychla.com/2010/10/is-net-type-safe.html), I've blogged about it. I haven't checked this for years, chances are this still works.

Comment: Note that what you're asking about is basically the whole concept of the Gen0 "heap" (note: not actually a heap, but serves the same dynamic allocation need) of the .NET GC/allocator.  It's a memory pool used for short-term allocation, but also has compaction.

Comment: @WiktorZychla That was exactly my first thought too! It's just that in C++ it is undefined to use a union that way, so I always want to make sure to use safe methods (most of the times at least :D )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like "reinterpret cast" as long as it is a [blittable type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/blittable-and-non-blittable-types).

```
public struct MyPoint
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
}
...
var bytes = new byte[8];
var points = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, MyPoint>(bytes.AsSpan());
points[0].X = 42; // points to same memory as 'bytes'
```

But if you start mixing in references this will fail at runtime. So this is only practical in fairly specific optimization scenarios where you have large buffers of some very simple, blittable, data type.

In general you need to learn how .Net manages memory and try to work with the garbage collector, not reuse C++ practices that do not belong in a managed environment.

A notable difference between C++ is that small object allocations are very cheap in .Net. It just involves incrementing a pointer in a memory segment and initializing the object header. To some extent you pay for it at garbage collection time, but you only pay for objects that are actually alive, not any garbage. There are plenty of articles digging deeper into memory and performance. The [Memory and GC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/memory?view=aspnetcore-7.0) page seem like a decent start.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solves my problem!

Comment: Yeah I understand the basics about GC generations and Large object heap I just do not have enough experience and fear the moment of Collection.  I usually work with big datasets and need to recycle memory, so I thought instead of creating a Generic<> Pool (or using ArrayPool), to just reuse a type agnostic pool with value types. But tbh I can live without that.   I just have this habit of trying to figure out optimal solutions to non-existant problems :D  Thanks a lot again!